# Django Template Autor-reload

Tags: django, templates, reload

How can i disable **Django 3.2** from reloading the server whenever i edit template files in development. This is actually making my productivity slow because it takes **1-4** secs to reload.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Docs is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-noreload)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that currently has a ticket on Django's issue tracker, see [Ticket #32744](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32744). This will be resolved in further versions, but until then from the discussion on the ticket itself we can see that the issue stems from the problem that newer Django projects use `pathlib.Path` while older projects just used strings for the paths. You can simply change your project settings to use `pathlib.Path` to solve this issue (at least for yourself). Make the following changes in `settings.py` (keep other settings unchanged):

```
from pathlib import Path


# Change the setting `BASE_DIR`
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# In the `DIRS` list of the setting `TEMPLATES`, for keeping it relevant I would only show that key
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'] # I don't show the other keys, but don't remove them!
    },
]


# the `DATABASES` setting if you use sqlite3
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the way to work:

```
for x in TEMPLATES:
    if 'OPTIONS' not in x:
        x['OPTIONS'] = {}

    x['OPTIONS']['debug'] = True  # True: reload template on change
                                  # False: no reload on change
```