# Django stop restarting the server if change in html

Tags: django

I created a website using django, in the webpage I linked a refresh button, when a user clicks the refresh button, it runs python script and update the static html page.
But what happening is, the django server restarts after each change in  the html and that leads to user unable to access during that particular time, because the service is down at that particular time. Could someone please tell me, how can I disable restarting the django if any change in html.

I'm starting django server as follows.
`python manage.py runserver`

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67640060/django-template-autor-reload/67640269#67640269 Although a user updates static html page?? You might want to reconsider making that a _media_ file.

Comment: @EPaul this question is different from the one you link (reloads should not be caused by template changes), it is a bug currently open in Django 3.2 see [Ticket #32744](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32744), unfortunately cannot mark as duplicate of my above linked question as none of the answers are upvoted.

Comment: @EPaul, yep --noreload helped to overcome the issue, thanks for  sharing the details.

Answer (score 0):

I used below command to stop restarting the server for any changes in the html.

`python manage.py runserver --noreload`

--noreload was the solution.